# RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear

Tags: node.js, websocket

someone keeps trying to crash my WebSocket server, and this error keeps getting sent when they try. Is there any possible fix to this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you have listener for `error`? `ws.on('error', console.error);`

Comment: Please read this https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1140 to understand the issue.